# Getting invalidCredentials for connection.bind in LDAP3

Tags: python-3.6, credentials, ldap3

I'm trying to write python code which will use LDAP module to validate LDAP connection:

```
import configuration
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SIMPLE, SYNC, ALL

server = Server(configuration.LDAP_SERVER, port=XXXX, get_info=ALL)
c = Connection(server, authentication=SIMPLE, user=configuration.LDAP_USER, password=configuration.LDAP_PASS, check_names=True, lazy=False, client_strategy=SYNC, raise_exceptions=False)
c.open()
c.bind()
```

When running the code, I'm getting:

```
{'result': 49, 'description': 'invalidCredentials', 'dn': '', 'message': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839\x00', 'referrals': None, 'saslCreds': None, 'type': 'bindResponse'}
```

I'm sure the user and password I'm using are correct.
can you advise what's wrong with the code?

Comment: any suggestion someone? :)

Comment: Do you have username in the form ```'domain\user'```?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use the user and pass which is used in all our applications for LDAP and AD validation.

Comment: AFAIK you have to specify which domain is used while connecting from python script. If you are passing only username it might result with InvalidCredentials error. Can you check that please?

Comment: It worked. publishing the full code. Tnx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to google it, but eventually, the below code worked:

```
import configuration
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SIMPLE, SYNC, ALL
server = Server(configuration.LDAP_SERVER, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, "CN=XXXXX,OU=XXX;OU=XXXX,OU=Users,XX=People,XX=corp,XX=[organization],XX=XXX", password=configuration.LDAP_PASS, auto_bind=False)
conn.bind()
print(conn)
```

Comment: Depending on LDAP server settings, ```auto_bind=False``` may be necessary to avoid a AcceptSecurityContext error prior to getting to ```conn.bind()```, even if the user/pwd info is in the ```Connection()``` call

Comment: In the latest version, it's changed as `auto_bind='NONE'`

Comment: What are you using for the password? Is that something given by your organization?